# How to get the unique count of strings

Tags: bash, shell, awk

These are some of the lines I have in a file. The idea is to get the unique count of blades in the file.

```
sS'/on/demandware.servlet/webdav/Sites/Logs/service-ACI_Preauth_Card-blade2-3.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-20201105.log'
sS'/on/demandware.servlet/webdav/Sites/Logs/service-ACI_Preauth_Card-blade5-0.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-20201105.log'
sS'/on/demandware.servlet/webdav/Sites/Logs/service-ACI_Preauth_Card-blade3-9.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-20201105.log'
sS'/on/demandware.servlet/webdav/Sites/Logs/service-ACI_Preauth_Card-blade4-5.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-20201104.log'
sS'/on/demandware.servlet/webdav/Sites/Logs/service-ACI_Preauth_Card-blade4-6.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-20201104.log'
sS'/on/demandware.servlet/webdav/Sites/Logs/service-ACI_Preauth_Card-blade4-5.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-20201103.log'
sS'/on/demandware.servlet/webdav/Sites/Logs/service-ACI_Preauth_Card-blade4-2.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-20201104.log'
sS'/on/demandware.servlet/webdav/Sites/Logs/service-ACI_Preauth_Card-blade3-9.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-20201104.log'
```

This is the script I've tried.

```
#!/bin/bash +x
pwd
cat *.p >> test.txt
awk '{ match($0,/[0-9]{8}/);arr[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]+=1;match($0,/blade/);spoint=RSTART+RLENGTH;match($0,/\.demandware/) } END { for (i in arr) { print i" - "arr[i]} } ' test.txt >> gen_output.txt
grep  "2020" gen_output.txt
```

all I get the output as

```
20201105 - 3
20201104 - 4
20201103 - 1
```

All the blades count on a single day is considered.

The desired output should be like

```
20201105 - 3
20201104 - 2 
20201103 - 1
```

(blade4 & blade3) on 20201104,
blade4 is repeated thrice, so that should be considered as one.
Please suggest some ideas here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
grep -Eo 'blade[0-9]+|[0-9]{8}' file | paste - - | sort -u | cut -f2 | sort | uniq -c
```

outputs

```
      1 20201103
      2 20201104
      3 20201105
```

Comment: Can you help get the count of blade2-5, blade5-0, blade3-9, blade4-5 instead of just blade2, blade5, blade3, blade4 ...

Comment: Those are all supposed to be counted separately? Just update the regex from `blade[0-9]+` to `blade[0-9]+-[0-9]+`

Answer (score 2):

You can get this done in a single `awk`:

```sh
awk 'match($0, /-blade[0-9]+/) {
   b = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
}
match($0, /[0-9]{8}/) {
   d = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
   if (!seen[d,b]++)
      freq[d]++
}
END {
   for (i in freq)
      print i, freq[i]
}' file
```

```
20201103 1
20201104 2
20201105 3
```

Comment: What is not working? See it working in the demo: https://ideone.com/6tho9g

Comment: There's a special place in the OPs name for people who just say `This isn't working.` :-).

Comment: oops, no offense. what I'm trying to say is 

I'm also getting data other than the actual. after some editing I'm good. Thanks.
can you help me with getting data extracted as blade 2-3 instead of blade 2.
So, it should count blade 1-2, blade 2-3 likewise.

Comment: As you already have an accepted answer any further changes should be incorporated there

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution(without sorting):*** Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -F"[-.]" '
match($0,/ACI_Preauth_Card-blade[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  if(!arr[val,$(NF-1)]++){
     arr1[$(NF-1)]++
  }
  val=""
}
END{
  for(key in arr1){
    print key" - "arr1[key]
  }
}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
20201103 - 1
20201104 - 2
20201105 - 3
```

---

---

***2nd solution(with sorting option of gawk):*** OR in case you have GNU `awk` and needed output in YYMMDD descending form then try following.

```
awk -F"[-.]" '
match($0,/ACI_Preauth_Card-blade[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  if(!arr[val,$(NF-1)]++){
    arr1[$(NF-1)]++
  }
  val=""
}
END{
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_desc"
  for(key in arr1){
     print key" - "arr1[key]
  }
}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
20201105 - 3
20201104 - 2
20201103 - 1
```

Comment: In real there will be hundreds of lines like 

    blade2-3.mon.demandware.net----20201105
    blade2-3.mon.demandware.net----20201105
    blade2-3.mon.demandware.net----20201105
    blade2-3.mon.demandware.net----20201105
    blade2-3.mon.demandware.net----20201105
    blade2-3.mon.demandware.net----20201105

    blade1-3.mon.demandware.net----20201104
    blade1-3.mon.demandware.net----20201104
    blade1-3.mon.demandware.net----20201104

all I want is
the total count should be 
    20201105 - 1 
    20201104 - 1
instead of 
    20201105 - 6
    20201104 - 3

Comment: @Hell, with your shown samples when I try this solution this works very well, please test it once with your provided samples, it worked well with it.

Comment: I'm getting 1 count less for 20201104 & 20201103. Getting good for 20201105 though. Can you pls check that once again. Thanks

Comment: @Hell, solution will be always given as per shown samples only, I had tested these solutions successfully with your posted samples if your actual data is different than shown samples then it's not going to work, kindly do let me know on same.